# single tap (hittest) does not fit with subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, subview, hittest

After changing the uiview position (y = -50) the single tap does not fit to the position to my added subviews. Hittest means the touchview starts at -50 and not 0. How to fix this?

```
myview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, mywidth, myheight)];
```

The single tap:

```
// SINGLE TAP
- (void)singleTapRecognized:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *touchView = [myview hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:nil];

    NSLog(@"Y touchPoint: %f",touchPoint.y);
    NSLog(@"Y touchView: %f",touchView.frame.origin.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:myview]; // <-- not self.view
```

Everything happens in myview. :-)